# I can't install next-themes

Tags: npm, next.js, shadcnui

I am trying to implement the [shadcn dark mode ui](https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/dark-mode/next), but the package isn't downloading. Here is what I get in the terminal when I enter `npm i next-themes`:

```
$ npm i next-themes  

up to date, audited 1716 packages in 4s

281 packages are looking for funding      
  run `npm fund` for details

15 vulnerabilities (5
 moderate, 10 high)  

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix      

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

The issue is that it doesn't show inside my package.json when I install it and when I try to import it, it can't be found. I thought it was because of my next version but I updated it and it still does not work.

Comment: I think you are installing that in to the wrong path

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the lock file **package-lock.json** After that clear the npm cache with the following command: `npm cache clean –force`.
Now try installing the package(s) again `npm install next-themes`